# midi timeout unpack folders

Tags: audio, drivers, midi

While running Logic Pro X, my computer suddenly pops up with:

> "Deep Architecture! Please unpack some folders!"

and

> "MIDI timeout Logic Pro has detected a MIDI timeout. Please restart
>   your computer and relaunch Logic Pro. If the problem persists, update
>   the drivers of all connected MIDI devices, (including Audio drivers
>   with MIDI functionality) to the latest version. For instructions on
>   removing old drivers, consult the manufacturers documentation."

What does this mean and how do I get it straight?

Answer (score 1):

I work with Logic Pro 9 and I had these messages lots of time.  It means nothing, it is a bug.  It has something to do with writing of automation.

What works for me is deleting all automation.

You do this by going to 'track" then "track automation" and then " delete all automation".

All your automation will be lost.

But then as you start record automation again, do "save as ...." everytime after recording an automation so you can go back if it happens again.

It's strange because I can work on tracks and it never happens and I can work on antother track and BOOM....